# software report the Missing awt error when start JProfiler

Tags: java, crash, jprofiler

on ubuntu 14.04, using openJDK8, When i start jprofiler, it has some error like below.
I struggle one day, at last still failed to start it.

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon$2.run(ImageIcon.java:130)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<clinit>(ImageIcon.java:100)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.ab.a(ejt:315)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.ab.<clinit>(ejt:47)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.E(ejt:1038)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.IntegrationApplication.main(ejt:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:62)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1847)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1670)
    ... 20 more
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:198)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at com.ejt.framework.gui.eo.<init>(ejt:37)
    at com.ejt.framework.gui.eo.a(ejt:17)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.ab.a(ejt:315)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.ab.<clinit>(ejt:47)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.E(ejt:1038)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.IntegrationApplication.main(ejt:8)

    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:62)
```

Answer (score 1):

This a new problem with Java 8u242. It will be fixed shortly in JProfiler 11.1.1. The temporary workaround is to run JProfiler with a different JRE.

---

Since there is some interest, I will explain what the bug was:

The reason for this bug is that JProfiler set the private field `ClassLoader.sys_paths` to null to force a reevaluation of the `java.library.path` system property. This was a common hack to add directories to the library pack so that dependent native libraries could be loaded. Since [a commit](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/commit/0c0e7e4d2ec7f3f20e7c40c3e1f6b7df91f6ebe4) that was released as part of 8u242, the new private method `ClassLoader.initLibraryPaths()`has to be called after setting that field to null, otherwise no native libraries can be loaded.

Comment: @Ingo Kegel, would you be able to elaborate what's the cause of the issue? I'm having the same when running tests on Travis, and would love to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that has been super helpful!